# Как работать с несколькими аккаунтами steam?

Tags: python, steam, steam-web-api

За основу взята библиотека [steampy](https://github.com/bukson/steampy/), написан gui под приложение и сейчас встал вопрос, а каким либо образом можно сделать так, чтобы все действия происходили сразу на нескольких аккаунтах, как сделать авторизацию для каждого аккаунта?
Авторизация, которая используется в steampy требует:

1. логин
2. пароль
3. АПИ ключ
4. файл Steamguard.txt в который входит (steamid, shared_secret, identity_secret) формат файла .json, однако расширение .txt.

Импорт мафайла для создания файла steamguard.txt реализован. Необходимо просто описать как сделать авторизацию сразу несколькими аккаунтами, как для каждого сгенерировать отдельный Steamguard.txt и где и как хранить файлы для каждого аккаунта, в которых будет логин, пароль, апи ключ?
Код функции импорта мафайла (если кому-то понадобится)

```
   #self.maFile - это путь до файла .maFile получаемый в результате ответа (выбора) пользователя
    with open(self.maFile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fdict:
        content = fdict.read()
    with open('maf.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(content)
    with open('maf.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as mfile:
        data = json.loads(mfile.read())
        shared = data['shared_secret']
        secret = data['identity_secret']
        steamid = data['Session']['SteamID']
        with open(f'Steamguard.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as guard:
            text = {
                "steamid": f"{steamid}",
                "shared_secret": f"{shared}",
                "identity_secret": f"{secret}"
            }
            json.dump(text, guard)
    os.remove('maf.json')
```

Хотелось бы создать отдельную папку, где будут хранится логины, пароли и апи ключи каждого аккаунта и туда-же будет создаваться файл Steamguard_{steamID}.txt + как-то подключить это к основному проекту, потому что сейчас логин, пароль апи ключ берется из файла config.py который находится в папке с основным проектом.